# nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost - ionic - ios14

Tags: ios14

Whenever I am trying to run my app on IOS 14 simulator I am getting this error multiple times.

> "nil host used in the call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost"

I have tried putting this in `AppDelegate.m` file also but did not work.

Comment: Are you using Lottie animation from airbnb?

Answer (score 1):

I had multiple instances of this warning. Removing certain Lottie animations solved most of them. However, I still had one instance of this error persist.

I found it came from an .svg file I created and imported to the Asset Catalog.  I clicked on this image and unchecked 'Preserve Vector Data' from the attributes inspector section. This resolved the runtime error.